# Let $\begin {bmatrix} 0&2q&r \\ p&q&-r\\p&-q&r \end{bmatrix}$. If $AA^{T} =I$, then find $|p|$

Tags: matrices

$$|A|=\pm 1$$

Solving the determinant gives 
$$-6pqr=\pm 1$$

Which doesn’t help much.

A separate solution states that

> A is an orthogonal matrix so $0+p^2+p^2=1 \implies p=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

I don’t have the justification for the statement that the solution so blatantly implied. Perhaps it’s a property I am not aware of.

So I want know to why my first approach got to a dead end and an explanation for the second solution

Thanks!

Comment: Just look at the diagonal entries when you multiply out $A^tA$.

Comment: You have to do the matrix multiplication and then individually equate its elements with that of identity matrix.

Comment: $AA^{T} =I \implies |A|=±1$ but not the other way round: the LHS of the implication contains *more* information than the RHS.

Comment: $AA^T=I$ is a *much* more restrictive condition than just $\det(A) = \pm 1$.

Comment: @Doubtnut I think it’s a standard property

Comment: The determinant throws away too much information to determine $\lvert p\rvert$ just from its value. You need to examine $AA^T$ itself more closely, but $A^TA$ is even better.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a matrix $A \in \text{Mat}_{n, n}(\mathbb{R})$ is orthogonal if $A^TA = AA^T = I_n$. Then, the columns of $A = [a_1 \mid \dots \mid a_n]$ form an orthonormal basis as 
$$\langle a_i, a_j \rangle = a_i^Ta_j = (A^TA)_{ij} = (I_n)_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$$
where $\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } i \neq j\\ 1 & \text{if } i = j\\\end{cases}$ is the Kronecker delta function. Therefore, every column must have a norm of 1. In particular here, $|a_1| = 1$, so $\sqrt{0+p^2 + p^2} = 1$, so $|p| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: For me it's not that obvious that $AA^T=I\Rightarrow A^TA=I$ for an _arbitrary_ $A$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Note that $AA^T = I \implies A^T = A^{-1} \implies A^TA = I$.

Comment: This completes the solution, indeed 1. $AA^T=I\Rightarrow A^TA=I$ 2. $(A^TA)_{1,1}=0+2p^2=1$ hence the desired result

Comment: More generally, if $AB=I$ then $BA=I$ (for square matrices $A,B$).

Answer (score 2):

Values of determinant of an orthogonal Matrix is ±1.
But every such Matrix need not be orthogonal i.e. converse of the statement above is not true.
Hence your first approach didn't give any results.
In the solution given next, find AA^T and compare corresponding elements with a Unit Matrix to get p

Comment: Yes, but I am fairly confident it’s standard property